# throwing IOException whle iterating

Tags: java, collections

I have a LevelDBIterator that I have to wrap in my own Java class which also implements Iterator and uses LevelDBIterator inside it. I have 2 issues:
1. LevelDB does file reads, so the method that is reading from the file system can throw IOException, how do throw it up in my `next()` method? Reason I ask this is because implementing `Iterator` won't let me throw any exception
2. Also, how do I close the underlying LevelDBIterator and when?

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class MyIterator implements AutoCloseable, Iterator<Employee> {
    Iterator<Employee> it;
    public MyIterator(Iterator<Employee> it) {
        this.it = it;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("close called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return it.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public Employee next() {
        return it.next();
    }
}
public class EmployeeList implements AutoCloseable,Iterable<Employee>{
    List<Employee> emplist;
    @Override
    public Iterator<Employee> iterator() {

        return new Iterator<Employee>() {
            private final Iterator<Employee> it = emplist.iterator();
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                System.out.println("called hasNext");
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Employee next() {
                return it.next();
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeList lst = new EmployeeList();
        lst.emplist = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.emplist.add(new Employee("name1", 10));
        lst.emplist.add(new Employee("name2", 20));
        lst.emplist.add(new Employee("name3", 30));
        System.out.println("Does close work?");
        try (MyIterator it = new MyIterator(lst.iterator())) {
           while(it.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println(it.next().name);
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("close called");
    }
```

Comment: `Iterator` is the wrong choice for iterating a resource that needs to be closed at the end of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) that requires a resource to be closed at the end of iteration, you should encapsulate that in an object implementing [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

E.g. if you normally would do:

```
for (MyObj obj : xxx.getSomeResource()) {
    // code here
}
```

Then change the code so you'd do this instead:

```
try (MyResource res = xxx.getSomeResource()) {
    for (MyObj obj : res) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Where `MyResource` would be something like:

```
class MyResource implements AutoCloseable, Iterable<MyObj> {
    private final LevelDBIterator levelDBIterator;
    public MyResource(LevelDBIterator levelDBIterator) {
        this.levelDBIterator = levelDBIterator;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<MyObj> iterator() {
        return /*code here*/;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.levelDBIterator.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I almost get what you suggested and thanks. I am pasting my code with your suggestion(I did not use LevelDB yet in my sample code but that must not matter). I am using ``hasNext`` route, and I know with Iterator I can do forEach the way you say but your suggestion for doing ``for`` is not compiling. I will paste my sample code now

Comment: Actually never mind, I got what you meant and the forEach also works. However, help me figure out, if there is a way to throw a checked exception by doing Iterable or any other way? Since currently I cannot throw anything other than ``NoSuchEle...`` and I do not want to suppress the IOException that might happen. I know I can wrap it too but still

Comment: @curiousengineer No, you can only throw unchecked exceptions from `Iterator` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How do throw it up in my next() method?

A: You can catch the exception, and then throw an unchecked [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

---

Q: How do I close the underlying LevelDBIterator and when?

A: In addition to implementing Iterator, you implement [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), and document that your iterator must be closed after use.
The user of your iterator can then close it explicitly, or use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).